# What is wrong with this for loop & timer?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript for loop and setTimeout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428091/javascript-for-loop-and-settimeout-issue)

I want this loop to change the html inside #leftValue from 0 to leftValue, start with 0 and rise up until leftValue value - but instead it changing the html inside #leftvalue to the value of leftValue without starting with 0.

any idea what am i doing wrong?

```
for (i=0; i<leftValue; i++)
{
    changeLeft(i);
}
function changeLeft(num)
{
    var leftTimer = setTimeout(function(){$('#leftValue').html(num+'%')},1000);
}
```

Comment: I believe it's because our for loop isn't dependent on the setTimeout so it's going to appear like it's skipping the 0 through leftValue...values when in reality it is producing them, but the timeout isn't having an effect..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your timers are registered at the same time, and will run 1000ms later (thus also all at the same time). You could have the timeout set to e.g. `num * 1000`. That way, the time a certain `num` shows up is dependent on that `num`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your loop is firing off a bunch of setTimeouts which will all start in around 1000 milliseconds.

You might want to use `setInterval` instead, which can progressively change a value (i.e., simple animation).